# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(k_0 \xi)e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2 t}}d\xi$

Tags: integration

I have a heat equation for which in the solution I need to evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(k_0 \xi)e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2 t}}d\xi$$
Except of the common gaussian integral ($\int_{-\infty}^\infty exp(-\alpha s^2 +\beta s)ds=\sqrt{\pi/\alpha}e^{\beta^2/4\alpha}$) by break the sine function to 2 exponents. I got a very long expression. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you just want [the result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms) or [the proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563578/evaluate-int-infty-infty-x-exp-x2-2-sin-xi-x-mathrm-dx?rq=1) ? and if you understand analytic continuation you can deduce $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- (x-a)^2}dx$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ from the result for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, after what you'll modify  it slightly  to get your integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe first that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(k_0\xi)e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2t}}\,d\xi
=\Im\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ik_0\xi}e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2t}}\,d\xi\right]
$$
Then notice that
\begin{align*}
ik_0\xi-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2t}
&=-\frac1{4a^2t}\left[\xi^2-2\left(ik_02a^2t+x\right)\xi+x^2\right]\\
&=-\frac1{4a^2t}\left[\xi-(ik_02a^2t+x)\right]^2+\frac{(ik_02a^2t+x)^2+x^2}{4a^2t}\\
&=-\left(\frac{\xi-\alpha}{2a\sqrt t}\right)^2+\beta
\end{align*}
(provided $t$ real and positive) where we have set
$$
\alpha:=ik_02a^2t+x\\
\beta:=\frac{\alpha^2+x^2}{4a^2t}
$$
thus we got
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ik_0\xi}e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{4a^2t}}\,d\xi
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\left(\frac{\xi-\alpha}{2a\sqrt t}\right)^2+\beta}\,d\xi\\
&=e^{\beta}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\left(\frac{\xi-\alpha}{2a\sqrt t}\right)^2}\,d\xi\\
\end{align*}
Then you can conclude by the substitution
$$
\frac{\xi-\alpha}{2a\sqrt t}=\eta
$$
using the Residue Theorem.