# Help with integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iαx-α^2 t} dα$

Tags: integration

Solve by integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iαx-α^2 t}   dα$$

solve by integration , this integral is - infinity to infinity and exponent value

Comment: Please make sure I edited it correctly. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has a short answer and a long one.

completing the square you have:
$$
e^{−iαx−α^2t}=e^{-t(\alpha+\frac{ix}{2t})} \,e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}} \\
\Rightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{−iαx−α^2t}\, d \alpha=e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t(\alpha+\frac{ix}{2t})^2} \,d\alpha \\=e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}} \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t\alpha^2} \,d\alpha \\=e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}
$$

But in the complete answer, we have to prove that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t(\alpha+b)^2} \,d\alpha=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t\alpha^2} \,d\alpha
$$

For that we can just use a change of variable, but $b$ is imaginary and that means that the limits of integration would change to a line in the complex plane.

So to prove that we need another approach and what is commonly done is to use the fact $e^{z^2}$ is an entire function, so any closed line integral in the complex plane will be $0$. So you choose a rectangle whose segments parallel to the real line go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ , and the other segments go from $0$ to some $ic$. Then you solve the 4 integrals for each segment and using that the sum of the 4 of them is $0$, you should get the desired result, that is, it is fine to complete the squares even if you have to deal with an imaginary term.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't quite the Fourier transform of a Gaussian, this link helps illustrate @Mhenni's idea:

http://www4.ncsu.edu/~franzen/public_html/CH795Z/math/ft/gaussian.html

Comment: i know the Fourier transform , here is the issu to compute it with "t"

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Complete the square in the argument of the exponential in terms of $\alpha$ and then use [Gaussian integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

**Added:** Note that, you need to make a change of variables after completing the square. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222028/how-do-i-compute-int-infty-infty-e-fracx22t-e-ikx-mathrm).

Comment: @maha: You should try to work out the problem.

Comment: @maha: See this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222028/how-do-i-compute-int-infty-infty-e-fracx22t-e-ikx-mathrm).

Comment: @downvoter: What's the downvote for?

Comment: @moderators: it seems some people are abusing the downvote option on this website. In my opinion you should find a solution to this problem. One solution is you can cancel this option and force people to leave a comment.