# How to do this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-x^{2}}\cos\left(\,kx\,\right)\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, quantum-mechanics

How to do this integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-x^{2}}\cos\left(\,kx\,\right)\,{\rm d}x$$

for any $k > 0$ ?.

I tried to use gamma function, but sometimes the series doesn't converge.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You need to use Gaussian integrals after changing the cos function in terms of the exponential and completing the squares. see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629360/help-with-integral-int-infty-infty-ei%CE%B1x-%CE%B12-t-d%CE%B1).

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/388356).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff There are a few improper integrals there... but this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral equals $\sqrt{\pi}e^{-k^2/4}$. To show this, just consider that:
$$ I =\Re\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ikx-x^2}\,dx = e^{-k^2/4}\cdot \Re\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-ik/2)^2}\,dx $$
and prove that the complex shift does not affect the value of the integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-ik/2)^2}\,dx = \int_{-\infty-ik/2}^{+\infty-ik/2}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$
This happens because $e^{-z^2}$ is an entire function whose absolute value when $|\Re(z)|\to +\infty$ and $\Im(z)$ stays bounded goes to zero really fast.

Answer (score 10):

We assume
$$F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos kxdx$$
Consider $F'(k)$, we have
$$F'(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-xe^{-x^2}\sin kxdx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x^2}\sin kx|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ke^{-x^2}\cos kxdx)$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}kF(k)$$
Then we solve the ordinary differential equation with $F(0)=\sqrt\pi$, and we get
$$F(k)=\sqrt\pi e^{\frac{-k^2}{4}}$$

Comment: That is pretty. Well played.

Comment: @msteve Thank you. But we must take care of the exchange of integral and derivative.

Comment: Is it not just differentiation under the integral sign, since the integrand is $C^1$ in both $x$ and $k$? Regardless though, just wanted to point out that I thought it was a neat trick to apply here.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$\cos kx = \frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2}.$$
Using the identity that for $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2+ibx}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}},$$that can be obtained completing squares, we find for $a=1$ and $b=k$ that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos kx dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2} \frac{e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}}{2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\frac{k^2}{4}}.$$