# Fourier Transform of a Gaussian Signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, integral-transforms

As far as I know this is the formula for FT : [image: FT Formula]

On this question on part b) I fint on the answer the part with e^-jwt is changed with cos(wt) I have no idea how cos(wt) came in ... would you please enlighten me?

[image: Promblem 2 b)]

Comment: The cosine comes into play because the Gaussian is even and so integrating it against sine gives 0.

Comment: For finding the Fourier transform, just use Gauss integrals. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222028/how-do-i-compute-int-infty-infty-e-fracx22t-e-ikx-mathrm).

Comment: @CameronWilliams there is no sine ...

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal there is no cos(wt) on the link you gave.

Comment: @Anarkie: Use the identity $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$.

Comment: You are aware that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$, right?

Comment: @CameronWilliams because it is even the isinx vanishes?

Comment: Yep. Integrating an even function against an odd function over a symmetric interval gives zero.

Comment: @CameronWilliams There are zillions of formulas I need to keep in mind, everything is equal to everything in one way ... facepalm... But thanks a lot...